# How do I make two relations using the same key in prisma?

Tags: database, mongodb, prisma

I'm using MongoDB, and I am attempting to make a `Game` model that relates to 2 `GameSession` models that link to an `AuthUser` model. I would prefer it to be one field because I don't want it to appear that there should be two `Game[]` per `GameSession`, when there should only be one.

Here is my current Prisma file, with unrelated auth models hidden:

```
model AuthUser {
  id            String        @id @map("_id")
  game_session  GameSession? 
  exp           Int           @default(0)
  level         Int           @default(1)
  username      String        @unique
  @@map("auth_user")
}

model Game {
  id          String    @id @map("_id") @default(cuid())
  initiatorSession   GameSession? @relation(name: "initiator", fields: [initiatorSessionID], references: [id]) // Error: "Error validating field `initiatorSession` in model `Game`: The relation field `initiatorSession` on model `Game` is missing an opposite relation field on the model `GameSession`. Either run `prisma format` or add it manually."
  initiatorSessionID String?    @unique
  opponentSession    GameSession? @relation(name: "opponent", fields: [opponentSessionID], references: [id]) // Error: "Error validating field `opponentSession` in model `Game`: The relation field `opponentSession` on model `Game` is missing an opposite relation field on the model `GameSession`. Either run `prisma format` or add it manually."
  opponentSessionID  String?    @unique
  isPlaying   Boolean   @default(false)
  turn        Player    @default(INITIATOR)
  board       Board

  @@map("game")
}

model GameSession {
  id String @id @map("_id") @default(cuid())
  game Game // Error: "Error validating field `game` in model `GameSession`: The relation field `game` on model `GameSession` is missing an opposite relation field on the model `Game`. Either run `prisma format` or add it manually."
  user AuthUser @relation(fields: [userID], references: [id])
  userID String @unique
  type Player // Initiator/Opponent
}
```